# Windows multicore program worked before but suddenly threads execute randomly

Tags: multithreading, nasm

Below is a multithreaded (4-core) NASM 64 program.  It's not minimal, but it's complete; I posted the complete code because a minimal example may not reveal the problem in this code.

This is my first multithreaded multicore program in NASM, and I was happy to see yesterday afternoon that it worked correctly (all four cores) and returned the values I was expecting.  I ran it successfully several times yesterday and again several times this morning.

Suddenly, about 10 minutes after my last run, without making any changes to the code, without re-assembling the dll, I ran it again and this time the threads execute randomly -- not all threads execute, and the configuration of threads that execute varies from run to run -- sometimes thread 1 only; sometimes threads 2-4 but not thread 1, sometimes only thread 2 and 4, etc.

My code did not have ExitThread or CloseHandle calls, so I added them in (see label_899:), rebooted and ran it again.  The first run after a fresh reboot still shows random execution of threads.

I thought the problem may be that CreateThread was failing, so I also returned the thread handles.  Every time, all four thread handles were created even though all did not execute, so that's not it.

I have done a lot of research but I haven't seen this issue discussed at all.  Even though this is NASM, the same thing could also be applicable to C or C++ multithreading.  I use WaitForMultipleObjects to wait on all threads to complete.

This is  a dll, and the entry point is Main_Entry_fn.  The dll is called from Python using ctypes, but I doubt that makes any difference.  I use ctypes frequently and have never had a problem with it.

Thanks for any ideas.

P.S. ignore the realloc code because the buffers are large enough that realloc is never called.

UPDATE:  Here is how I constructed the progam flow:  the entry point is Main_Entry_fn toward the bottom of the program listing (it's an export because it has to be exported for a dll call).  Main_Entry_fn takes the input data from the calling function, preserves registers (because the whole program is register optimized) and allocates output buffers.  Main_Entry_fn then calls Init_Cores_fn (top of program listing), where we create four arrays with data for the registers on entry to each core (remember all vars are stored in registers -- see the call to DupThreadInfo), and creates four threads in a loop.  The threads all call Prime_Number_fn, and the threads are set to start immediately upon creation.

Register assignments:

r15 list_of_results_ptr (pointer to list_of_results)

r14 list_of_results_ctr (counter for list_of_results)

r13 list_of_results_length

r12 numbers_ptr (pointer to "numbers" input array)

r11 numbers_ctr

r10 numbers_length

r9  num

r8  i

xmm15   num_float

xmm14:  result

```
; Header Section
[BITS 64]
[default rel]
extern malloc, calloc, realloc, free
global Main_Entry_fn
export Main_Entry_fn
global FreeMem_fn
export FreeMem_fn
extern CreateThread, CloseHandle, ExitThread
extern WaitForMultipleObjects, GetCurrentThread

section .data align=16
Return_Pointer_Array: dq 0, 0, 0
Input_Length_Array: dq 0, 0,
list_of_results_ptr: dq 0
list_of_results_ctr: dq 0
list_of_results_length: dq 0
data_master_ptr: dq 0
initial_dynamic_length: dq 0
internal_dynamic_length: dq 5000
XMM_Stack: dq 0, 0, 0
numbers_ptr: dq 0
numbers_length: dq 0
numbers: dq 0
list_of_results: dq 0
num_float: dq 0.0
loop_counter_401: dq 0
numbers_ctr: dq 0
num: dq 0
result: dq 0
const_1: dq 1
i: dq 0
range_loop_start_i: dq 0
range_loop_end_i: dq 0
const_0: dq 0
; New vars for threads:
ThreadCount:  times 4 dq 0
ThreadInfo: times 10 dq 0
ThreadInfo2: times 10 dq 0
ThreadInfo3: times 10 dq 0
ThreadInfo4: times 10 dq 0
TestInfo: times 4 dq 0
ThreadHandles: times 4 dq 0
Return_Data_Array: times 8 dq 0 ; ptr,ptr,ptr,ptr,length,length,length,length
StartByte: dq 0
stride: dq 8
output_buffer_pointers: times 4 dq 0 ; for malloc
Division_Size: dq 0
Division_Start: dq 0

section .text

; ______________________________________

Init_Cores_fn:

; Calculate the data divisions
mov rax,r10
mov rbx,4 ;cores
xor rdx,rdx
div rbx
mov [Division_Size],rax
mov [Division_Start],rax

; Populate the ThreadInfo array with vars to pass
; ThreadInfo: length, startbyte, stride, vars into registers on entry to each   core
mov rdi,ThreadInfo
mov rax,0 ;ThreadInfoLength
mov [rdi],rax       ; length (number of vars into registers plus 3 elements)
mov rax,[stride]
mov [rdi+16],rax    ; 8 x number of cores (32 in this example)
; Vars (these registers are populated on main entry)
mov rbp,output_buffer_pointers
mov rax,[rbp]
mov [rdi+24],rax ;for r15
mov [rdi+32],r14
mov [rdi+40],r13
mov [rdi+48],r12
mov rax,[Division_Start]
mov [rdi+56],rax
mov rax,0
mov [rdi+64],rax

call DupThreadInfo

mov rbp,rsp ; preserve caller's stack frame
sub rsp,56 ; Shadow space (was 32)

; _____

label_0:

mov rax,[StartByte]
cmp rax,0
jne sb2
mov rdi,ThreadInfo
jmp sb5
sb2:cmp rax,8
jne sb3
mov rdi,ThreadInfo2
jmp sb5
sb3:cmp rax,16
jne sb4
mov rdi,ThreadInfo3
jmp sb5
sb4:cmp rax,24
jne sb5
mov rdi,ThreadInfo4
sb5:

; _____
; Create Threads

mov rcx,0               ; lpThreadAttributes (Security Attributes)
mov rdx,0               ; dwStackSize
mov r8,PrimeNumber_fn       ; lpStartAddress (function pointer)

mov r9,rdi              ; lpParameter (array of data passed to each core)

mov rax,0
mov [rsp+32],rax            ; use default creation flags
mov rdi,ThreadCount
mov [rsp+40],rdi            ; ThreadID

call CreateThread

; Move the handle into ThreadHandles array (returned in rax)
mov rdi,ThreadHandles
mov rcx,[StartByte]
mov [rdi+rcx],rax

mov rax,[StartByte]
add rax,8
mov [StartByte],rax
mov rbx,32 ; Four cores
cmp rax,rbx
jl label_0

; _____
; Wait

mov rcx,4 ;rax          ; number of handles
mov rdx,ThreadHandles       ; pointer to handles array
mov r8,0                ; wait for all threads to complete
mov r9,5000         ; milliseconds to wait

call WaitForMultipleObjects

; _____

mov rsp,rbp
jmp label_900

; ______________________________________

PrimeNumber_fn:

; Populate registers
;(note: rcx is the return value for ThreadProc)
mov rdi,rcx
mov rax,[rdi]
mov r15,[rdi+24]
mov r13,[rdi+40]
mov r12,[rdi+48]
mov r10,[rdi+56]
xor r11,r11
xor r9,r9
mov r8,[rdi+8] ; start byte
pxor xmm15,xmm15
pxor xmm15,xmm14
pxor xmm15,xmm13

; Get the ThreadID based on startbyte
mov rax,[rdi+72] ; 0, 8, 16, 24 for 4-core
push rax

;______

label_401:
mov rdi,r12 ; Pointer
cmp r8,r10
jge label_899
movsd xmm0,qword[rdi+r8]
movsd xmm15,xmm0
add r8,8
;______

cvttsd2si rax,xmm15
mov r9,rax
;______
label_8010:
label_801:
cmp r9,[const_1]
jle label_401
;______

label_12010:
mov rax,2
sub rax,1
movq xmm13,rax
label_1201:
movq rcx,xmm13
movq xmm1,[const_1]
addsd xmm13,xmm1
movq rcx,xmm13
mov rdx,r9
cmp rcx,rdx
jge label_12020
;______
label_16010: 
label_1601:
mov rax,r9
movq rbx,xmm13
xor rdx,rdx
div rbx
mov rax,rdx
mov rdx,0
cmp rax,rdx
jne label_16020
;______

movq xmm14,[const_0]
;______

movq rax,xmm14
cvtsi2sd xmm0,rax
movsd [r15+r14],xmm14
add r14,8
mov rax,r13
cmp r14,rax
jl next_17
 ;[Irrelevant code omitted]
next_17:
;______

jmp label_401
;______

label_1602:
label_16020:
;______

mov rax,r9
cvtsi2sd xmm14,rax
;______

movq rax,xmm14
cvtsi2sd xmm0,rax
movsd [r15+r14],xmm14
add r14,8
mov rax,r13
cmp r14,rax
jl next_21
 ;[Irrelevant code omitted]
next_21:
jmp label_1201
;______

label_1202:
label_12020:
;______

movq xmm14,[const_0]
;______

movq rax,xmm14
cvtsi2sd xmm0,rax
movsd [r15+r14],xmm14
add r14,8
mov rax,r13
cmp r14,rax
jl next_25
 ;[Irrelevant code omitted]
next_25:
jmp label_401

;______

label_899:

pop rax
mov rdi,Return_Data_Array
mov [rdi+rax],r15
mov [rdi+rax+32],r14 ; 32 = four cores

call ExitThread
call GetCurrentThread
mov rcx,rax
call CloseHandle

ret

; __________

label_900:

exit_label_for_PrimeNumber_fn:

mov rdi,Return_Data_Array ; Final return to the calling process
mov rax,rdi

ret

;__________
;Free the memory

FreeMem_fn:
sub rsp,40
call free
add rsp,40
ret

; __________
; Main Entry

Main_Entry_fn:
push rdi
push rbp
push rbx
push r15
xor r15,r15
push r14
xor r14,r14
push r13
xor r13,r13
push r12
xor r12,r12
push r11
xor r11,r11
push r10
xor r10,r10
push r9
xor r9,r9
movsd [XMM_Stack+0],xmm15
movsd [XMM_Stack+8],xmm14
movsd [XMM_Stack+16],xmm13
push r8
xor r8,r8
mov [numbers_ptr],rcx
mov [data_master_ptr],rdx
; Now assign lengths
lea rdi,[data_master_ptr]
mov rbp,[rdi]
xor rcx,rcx
movsd xmm0,qword[rbp+rcx]
cvttsd2si rax,xmm0
mov [numbers_length],rax
add rcx,8
; __________
; malloc for dynamic arrays
lea rdi,[data_master_ptr]
mov rbp,[rdi]
movsd xmm0,qword[rbp]
cvttsd2si rax,xmm0
mov r8,rax
mov rdx,10
mul rdx
mov rdx,10000000
cmp rax,rdx
jl malloc_next
mov rax,r8
malloc_next:
mov rax,50000000
mov [initial_dynamic_length],rax
;__________
; Output buffer #1
mov rcx,qword[initial_dynamic_length] ; Initial size
xor rax,rax
sub rsp,40
call malloc
mov rdi,output_buffer_pointers
mov [rdi],rax
add rsp,40
mov rax,qword[initial_dynamic_length]
mov [list_of_results_length],rax
;__________
; Output buffer #2
mov rcx,qword[initial_dynamic_length] ; Initial size
xor rax,rax
sub rsp,40
call malloc
mov rdi,output_buffer_pointers
mov [rdi+8],rax
add rsp,40
mov rax,qword[initial_dynamic_length]
mov [list_of_results_length],rax
;__________
; Output buffer #3
mov rcx,qword[initial_dynamic_length] ; Initial size
xor rax,rax
sub rsp,40
call malloc
mov rdi,output_buffer_pointers
mov [rdi+16],rax
add rsp,40
mov rax,qword[initial_dynamic_length]
mov [list_of_results_length],rax
;__________
; Output buffer #4
mov rcx,qword[initial_dynamic_length] ; Initial size
xor rax,rax
sub rsp,40
call malloc
mov rdi,output_buffer_pointers
mov [rdi+24],rax
add rsp,40
mov rax,qword[initial_dynamic_length]
mov [list_of_results_length],rax
; __________
; Write variables to assigned registers
lea rdi,[rel list_of_results_ptr]
mov r15,qword[rdi]
mov r14,[list_of_results_ctr]
mov r13,[list_of_results_length]
lea rdi,[rel numbers_ptr]
mov r12,qword[rdi]
mov r11,[numbers_ctr]
mov r10,[numbers_length]
mov r9,[num]
movsd xmm15,[num_float]
movsd xmm14,[result]
movsd xmm13,[i]
mov r8,[loop_counter_401]
; __________

call Init_Cores_fn

exit_label_for_Main_Entry_fn:
pop r8
movsd xmm13,[XMM_Stack+0]
movsd xmm14,[XMM_Stack+8]
movsd xmm15,[XMM_Stack+16]
pop r9
pop r10
pop r11
pop r12
pop r13
pop r14
pop r15
pop rbx
pop rbp
pop rdi
ret
;_____________

DupThreadInfo:
mov rdi,ThreadInfo2
; StartByte and EndByte
mov rax,[Division_Start]
mov [rdi+8],rax
add rax,[Division_Size]
mov [Division_Start],rax
sub rax,8
mov [rdi+56],rax
mov rax,[stride]
mov [rdi+16],rax    ; 8 x number of cores (32 in this example)
; Vars (these registers are populated on main entry)
mov rbp,output_buffer_pointers
mov rax,[rbp+8]
mov [rdi+24],rax
mov rax,8
mov [rdi+32],rax
mov [rdi+40],r13
mov [rdi+48],r12
; 56 is above
mov rax,8
mov [rdi+64],rax
mov rax,8 ; Thread number based on startbyte, for Return_Data_Array
mov [rdi+72],rax
; _____

mov rdi,ThreadInfo3
; StartByte and EndByte
mov rax,[Division_Start]
mov [rdi+8],rax
mov rbx,[Division_Size]
add rax,rbx
mov [Division_Start],rax
sub rax,8
mov [rdi+56],rax
mov rax,[stride]
mov [rdi+16],rax    ; 8 x number of cores (32 in this example)
; Vars (these registers are populated on main entry)
mov rbp,output_buffer_pointers
mov rax,[rbp+16]
mov [rdi+24],rax
mov rax,16
mov [rdi+32],rax
mov [rdi+40],r13
mov [rdi+48],r12
; [rdi+56] is above
mov rax,16
mov [rdi+64],rax
mov rax,16 ; Thread number based on startbyte, for Return_Data_Array
mov [rdi+72],rax

mov rdi,ThreadInfo4
; StartByte and EndByte
mov rax,[Division_Start]
mov [rdi+8],rax
mov rax,[numbers_length] ; final segment goes to the end
mov [rdi+56],rax
mov rax,[stride]
mov [rdi+16],rax    ; 8 x number of cores (32 in this example)
; Vars (these registers are populated on main entry)
mov rbp,output_buffer_pointers
mov rax,[rbp+24]
mov [rdi+24],rax
mov rax,24
mov [rdi+32],rax
mov [rdi+40],r13
mov [rdi+48],r12
; [rdi+56] is above
mov rax,24
mov [rdi+64],rax
mov rax,24 ; Thread number based on startbyte, for Return_Data_Array
mov [rdi+72],rax
ret
```

Comment: I keep reminding you that you are not following the ABI rules. You are modifying registers that you are required to preserve.

Comment: @Raymond Chen - do you mean before thread instantiation, or on entry to each core?

Comment: Your code is very hard to follow. It's not even clear where execution begins. I think it's at `Main_Entry_fn` (though there is no directive saying so), but you are using values in `rcx` and `rdx` which are not defined for the Windows process entry point. You make no attempt to describe what this code does; all you say is that sometimes it runs "successfully". "Now assign lengths" - but what are these the lengths of? What is the "data master pointer"? You need to explain the purpose of this code before anybody can try to understand it.

Comment: All of your threads are sharing the `Registers_In_V` global variables, so they corrupt each other. Your code is very hard to follow seeing as the comments do not provide any real guidance as to what this code is trying to do. I still don't know what you're trying to do - merely following the flow of control was hard enough. And again, you are not following the ABI rules regarding stack and register usage.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  In the post above I say this is a dll and the entry point is Main_Entry_fn.  The values for rcx, rdx, r8 and r9 are passed from the calling process (not shown) -- in this case, Python, but this dll could be called from other languages.  The Registers_In_V global variables are not used by any thread because they are only used on realloc, which does not happen during my run; I have omitted it now.  The program calculates prime numbers (at Prime_Number_fn) over an input array, but that doesn't answer why cores execute randomly, after having executed correctly.

Comment: My question can be simplified:  I create threads in the section headed "Create Threads" and pass PrimeNumber_fn (all four cores execute that function).  Looking at PrimeNumber_fn, is there anything about it that would cause cores to execute randomly?  The entry code below label_900 is not likely to be the cause.  I simplifed the code above to remove unnecessary code, but I can't make it much simpler than that because we are initiating four cores which calls for a lot of code in assembler.

Comment: The entry point for a DLL is called in a very specific way, not the way you described here. As I noted, the problem is in the use of the `Registers_In_V` variables, which are shared between threads with no synchronization. You later deleted those variables and wrote "Irrelevant code omitted" but in fact that is the code that is causing the problems.

Comment: The Registers_In and Registers_Out arrays are only used on realloc, which does not happen in my tests, so they have no effect on the outcome.  I just tested to verify and realloc does not occur (no calls to Registers_In) because I allocated 50MB for each of the four output buffers when they each need only about 12MB for the 4MB input array I used.  with a larger input array, at some point realloc would be called and then it would be a problem but it's not now.  Something else is causing the problem I am having now.

Comment: The entry point is being called correctly here because if it wasn't then I would not have gotten correct results, but I did.  The only problem is that I need the results from all four cores.

Comment: The system defines the DLL entry point. I think what you're calling the "entry point" is really an export. But at any rate, this code is undecipherable.

Comment: I updated the original post with information on how I constructed the program flow.  I realize this is a long listing; I hope that helps to follow it to where the problem seems to occur.

Comment: Your code still is hard to follow. None of the registers are commented. What is `r9`? What is `r10`? What is `ThreadInfo+24`? I did manage to figure out that you don't fill the entire output array, so you return uninitialized data to the caller.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am gathering some information to reply to your questions.

Comment: I just updated my post to show the register assignments.  ThreadInfo+24 is r15 (the pointer to the output buffer list_of_results).  The input data is an array of floats which are converted to integer on entry.  The input array is divided into four equal sections with each core taking one section.  Each core gets it own output buffer list_of_results.

Comment: As a test, I inserted code just below the startpoint of Prime_Number_fn to collect the thread IDs for each of the four cores and put them into a 4-element array (using a call to GetCurrentThreadId).  It shows that not all threads even make it into the function they are supposed to call.  So something is wrong in the core initialization, not the Prime_Number program.

Comment: You need to reduce the program to make it the smallest program that demonstrates the problem. Also, if you can demonstrate the problem in a higher-level language, that would remove the need to study every line of assembly. It's really not reasonable to expect someone to reverse-engineer your code like this.

Comment: Have you checked that you are following stack alignment requirements?

Comment: I am working now on creating a simpler example.  If I reproduce this in C and disassemble the executable, I will only see the opcodes; it won't show me what is wrong with the Windows API calls in NASM.  What puzzles me most is that it's clear that not all threads even enter Prime_Number, although I get four thread handles returned.  I don't see where the problem could be coming from in my code if not all threads even enter the function they are supposed to call after creation.  But I'm still working on it.  Thanks very much for your continued assistance on this.

Comment: The stack is aligned in the main thread just below the line "call DupThreadInfo" with the following two lines: "mov rbp,rsp / sub rsp,56".  There is no need for stack alignment in the cores (which I guess would be aligned right after entry to Prime_Number if it was needed).

Comment: On x64, stacks are misaligned on entry due to the 8-byte push implicit in the `call` instruction. You need to realign the stack. I'm not going to respond to this thread any longer. You need to minimize the code.

Comment: It's aligned by subtracting 56, which is three 16-bytes followed by 1 eight byte.  Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: I posted a simplified question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55147832/windows-nasm-threads-enter-their-function-but-return-results-randomly